# Remove spacing in flexbox navbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hi I am a beginner in web development. I'll be clear this is homework and after trying a lot of things I can't get it done so here I am. I was given an assignment to make a clone of the university's website but with our own styles and I have run into a bit of a problem. I want to remove all the spacing in the navbar as it doesn't look good.

I have seen posts with people putting negative margin but those were very old posts so I figured there must be a better modern approach.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/pr1232/pen/MWJPooq

I have put a `background-color` on the links and I want that color to fill the entire height of the navbar and no spaces between adjacent links. The color right now is just for highlighting purposes. I tried to do the same with padding but then I had to hardcode a value.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
/**
Font families: 

    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
*/
:root {
    --default-bg-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
    --charcoal-blue: #34495E;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--default-bg-color);
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    color: var(--charcoal-blue);
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.5em;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

header,
footer {
    background-color: var(--charcoal-blue);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* solution */
footer ul,
header nav ul {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}

footer a,
header nav a {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700&family=Noto+Sans+JP&family=Open+Sans&family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title>Portfolio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/svg/hexagon-with-right-arrow.svg" alt="Website Logo"/></a>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="pages/about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/registration.html">Registration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/faculty.html">Faculty</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/fee-structure.html">Fee Structure</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/login.html">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <h1>I am Nitesh.
                <br/>I build websites
                <br/>and other cool stuff.</h1>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <!--
                        ---Social Media Links---
                  -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Github</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Linkedin</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
            </ul>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you state "flexbox navbar" in your title, your actual navigation element doesn't have a flexbox styling. Therefore, the [spaces you have in your markup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/6252717) get rendered in the browser.

You can use flexbox display to achieve the desired effect, using your existant markup. All you need to do to accomplish that is set the `display:flex` property, like so:

```
nav ul {
  display:flex;
}
```

Comment: This is good and answers part of the question but I also want to get rid of the spacing around the `ul` the blue part. What i want is something that looks like the w3schools.com navbar that has no spacing between the `li` elements and the header itself

Comment: @nitesh_ I'm not quite sure what you mean... please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as suggested in the comment, together with a more detailed description of what you're trying to get, then I can look at it again.

Comment: I have updated the post and made the changes you had previously suggested and some others as well. Please look at it and suggest something.